# Azure function v4 unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-functions

How can i test azure function this is an example generated function:

```
public static class Test
{
    [Function("Test")]
    public static HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
        FunctionContext executionContext)
    {
        var logger = executionContext.GetLogger("BLEbLE");
        logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

        response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

        return response;
    }
}
```

i have generated method and i tried testing it with xunit but i don't how to mock HttpRequestData , FunctionContext and HttpResponseData, these are abstract classes so should i create custom classes for them and inherit for this 3 or maybe there is other way to test it?

Answer (score 2):

Tried with the below code snippet:

```
//Arrange
var context = Substitute.For<FunctionContext>();
var request = Substitute.For<HttpRequestData>(context);
var response = Substitute.For<HttpResponseData>(context);

var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton(Options.Create(new WorkerOptions{Serializer = new JsonObjectSerializer()}));

var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
context.InstanceServices.ReturnsForAnyArgs(serviceProvider);

request.Headers.ReturnsForAnyArgs(new HttpHeadersCollection());
response.Headers.ReturnsForAnyArgs(new HttpHeadersCollection());
response.Body.ReturnsForAnyArgs(new MemoryStream());
request.CreateResponse().ReturnsForAnyArgs(response);

var function = new Function();

//Act
var result = await function.Run(request);
result.Body.Position = 0;
var content = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<ErrorResponse>(result.Body);

//Assert
Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, result.StatusCode);
Assert.Equal("Error", content?.Message);
```

There is a documentation on migrating the Azure Functions in-process to Isolated worker process but no information on implementing the Tests like Unit, Integration Tests.

Microsoft Azure Team has taken this implementation of complete test framework for the isolated-workers process as a priority item #[281](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/281) and given the above code snippet for the temporary workaround.

Comment: Wouldn't it be great if all those types like `HttpRquestData` were available and used as interfaces, to make classes or methods testable from the outset? It's not rocket-science but I guess we have to wait until it catches on at Microsoft....

Comment: Sadly, this does not work for me on functions isolated worker 1.17.2. I completely agree with @Manfred, MS code does not follow patterns to make their frameworks testable and I don't know why. It causes an enormous amount of productivity loss in our industry as their tools are so widespread. Azure/EF and other frameworks have always been difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can create a Fake

from https://github.com/simon-k/fake-http-request-data/blob/main/FakeHttpRequestData/FakeHttpRequestData.cs

```cs
public class FakeHttpRequestData
    : HttpRequestData
{
    public FakeHttpRequestData(
        FunctionContext functionContext,
        Stream? body = null,
        string method = "GET",
        string? url = null)
        : base(functionContext)
    {
        Body = body ?? new MemoryStream();
        Headers = new HttpHeadersCollection();
        Cookies = new List<IHttpCookie>();
        Url = new Uri(url ?? "https://localhost");
        Identities = new List<ClaimsIdentity>();
        Method = method;
    }

    public override Stream Body { get; }

    public override HttpHeadersCollection Headers { get; }

    public override IReadOnlyCollection<IHttpCookie> Cookies { get; }

    public override Uri Url { get; }

    public override IEnumerable<ClaimsIdentity> Identities { get; }

    public override string Method { get; }

    public override HttpResponseData CreateResponse()
    {
        return new FakeHttpResponseData(FunctionContext, HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```